# DocumentDB request charge when no results

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I hope someone from CosmosDB team could clarify this.

For example, if we take a look at example from the official 'Performance Tips':

```
IDocumentQuery<Document> query = (from doc in client.CreateDocumentQuery(colSelfLink) where doc.Id == "myId" select document).AsDocumentQuery(); 
            Document myDocument = null;
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                FeedResponse<Document> res = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Document>();
                if (res.Count != 0) {
                    myDocument = res.Single();
                    break;
                }
           }
```

ref: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/performance-tips-for-azure-documentdb-part-1-2/

ref2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips

In the examples above, if we assume that query does not return any results, meaning `HasMoreResults` is false from the begining, 2 questions:

1. Is there any request charge if `ExecuteNextAsync` does not run at all? (since `HasMoreResults` is always false)?
2. If the answer to question 1) is 'yes', how to get that request charge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IDocumentQuery` implementation always returns `HasMoreResults` of `true` for the first call, so ExecuteNextAsync will always be executed at least once. Every query is submitted to the server, and incurs a minimal RU charge.

Comment: Thanks for youw answer. Ok, i was probably a bit imprecise. Let me add a detail: if second `HasMoreResults` returns `false`, so that `ExecuteNextAsync` doesn't get executed second time, will `HasMoreResults` introduce additional request charge? and if so - how to get info about that?

Comment: or actually, first one is probably `true` by default and subsequent ones are set by previous `ExecuteNextAsync` call. Is that the case?

Comment: yes, "first one is true by default and subsequent ones are set by previous ExecuteNextAsync call". HasMoreResults is just (lastContinuationToken != null)

Comment: oh, oh, right. now it makes sense. thanks for clarification!